# Draw a Stack Memory Layout for a C function

Tags: c, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow, stack-memory

I have been studying about **buffer overflow** and **vulnerable C programs** lately. I'm stuck on how to draw the stack memory layout for a C program with multiple buffer arrays as a local variable. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include. <string.h>

void CollectFunction(){
   char buffer[20];
   int a;
   char secretCode[30];

  printf("Enter your information: \n");
  gets(buffer);


  SeparateFunction(buffer); // this function collects the input value of buffer
}


int main(){
  CollectFunction();
  
  return 0;
}
```

Attached is my attempt so far.

[image]

**Question**: do I need to arrange all local variables of *CollectFunction()* in grid before the *Return Address*? Any hint or better solution is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `C` language does not know anything about the stack so it is not possible to draw C stack structure. You need to ask about implementation and particular ABI as possible implementations are almost countless

Comment: .. it might be possible though if you know exactly how this code is compiled.

Comment: Your stack representation is fine. But note that the compiler can arrange the local variables in any order, and there can be any amount of padding  bytes, canary bytes, or other bytes before, after, and  between the variables.

Comment: Return address might not be on the stack if processor (like ARM) uses link registers

Comment: Also some of the local variables might be in registers, some can be optimized out completely, the flow might be optimized too (like certain function calls are inlined, tail recursions unrolled and such)

Comment: Thanks all for your prompt comments. Do I need to disassemble binary executable with "objdump" to figure this out @user3386109?

Comment: "objdump" is one approach. Other approaches are to request the assembly from the compiler, or just step through the code with a debugger. For gcc or clang `-S` will output the assembly.

Comment: That's cool. Thanks everyone for the insight